# how do i fix Objective Value: None in Mip python

Tags: python

this is my first time using Python,
I tried to use mip to solve a fuzzy MRP case with the objective model and the code below.
But I met a problem when ran the code: Objective Value: None.
I don't understand why the following doesn't give a solution. Can someone tell me why this happened?
how can I fix it? thanks for any hint!

```
from mip import Model, xsum, MINIMIZE, BINARY
import random
import numpy as np
I, R, T, J = 30, 4, 12, 3
d = np.array ([
    [0, 25, 20, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20, 25, 25],
    [0, 15, 13, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 15],
    [0, 35, 30, 25, 25, 25, 15, 15, 15, 25, 25, 30, 35],
    [0, 11.8125, 10.35, 9, 8.6625, 7.65, 7.0875, 7.875, 9.1125, 10.6875, 10.35, 14.625, 12.0375],
    [0, 6142.5, 5382, 4680, 4504.5, 3978, 3685.5, 4095, 4738.5, 5557.5, 5382, 7605, 6259.5],
    [0, 27.5625, 24.15, 21, 20.2125, 17.85, 16.5375, 18.375, 21.2625, 24.9375, 24.15, 34.125, 28.0875],
    [0, 11.8125, 10.35, 9, 8.6625, 7.65, 7.0875, 7.875, 9.1125, 10.6875, 10.35, 14.625, 12.0375],
    [0, 1.18125, 1.035, 0.9, 0.86625, 0.765, 0.70875, 0.7875, 0.91125, 1.06875, 1.035, 1.4625, 1.20375],
    [0, 0.7875, 0.69, 0.6, 0.5775, 0.51, 0.4725, 0.525, 0.6075, 0.7125, 0.69, 0.975, 0.8025],
    [0, 70.875, 62.1, 54, 51.975, 45.9, 42.525, 47.25, 54.675, 64.125, 62.1, 87.75, 72.225],
    [0, 133.875, 117.3, 102, 98.175, 86.7, 80.325, 89.25, 103.275, 121.125, 117.3, 165.75, 136.425],
    [0, 866.25, 759, 660, 635.25, 561, 519.75, 577.5, 668.25, 783.75, 759, 1072.5, 882.75],
    [0, 452.8125, 396.75, 345, 332.0625, 293.25, 271.6875, 301.875, 349.3125, 409.6875, 396.75, 560.625, 461.4375],
    [0, 1299.375, 1138.5, 990, 952.875, 841.5, 779.625, 866.25, 1002.375, 1175.625, 1138.5, 1608.75, 1324.125],
    [0, 78.75, 69, 60, 57.75, 51, 47.25, 52.5, 60.75, 71.25, 69, 97.5, 80.25],
    [0, 787.5, 690, 600, 577.5, 510, 472.5, 525, 607.5, 712.5, 690, 975, 802.5],
    [0, 21.65625, 18.975, 16.5, 15.84375, 14.025, 12.9375, 14.4375, 16.71875, 19.59375, 18.975, 26.8125, 22.06875],
    [0, 112.5, 98.25, 85.5, 82.125, 72.75, 67.5, 75, 86.625, 101.25, 98.25, 138.75, 114.375],
    [0, 7.87, 6.87, 6, 5.775, 5.1, 4.725, 5.25, 6.075, 7.125, 6.87, 9.75, 8.025],
    [0, 787.5, 690, 600, 577.5, 510, 472.5, 525, 607.5, 712.5, 690, 975, 802.5],
    [0, 7.875, 6.9, 6, 5.775, 5.1, 4.725, 5.25, 6.075, 7.125, 6.9, 9.75, 8.025],
    [0, 21.65625, 18.975, 16.5, 15.84375, 14.025, 12.9375, 14.4375, 16.71875, 19.59375, 18.975, 26.8125, 22.06875],
    [0, 7.875, 6.9, 6, 5.775, 5.1, 4.725, 5.25, 6.075, 7.125, 6.9, 9.75, 8.025],
    [0, 6.565, 5.74, 5, 4.8175, 4.255, 3.9375, 4.375, 5.065, 5.935, 5.74, 8.125, 6.6925],
    [0, 168.75, 147, 128, 123, 108.75, 100.5, 111.75, 129, 151.5, 147, 207, 170.25],
    [0, 27.5625, 24.15, 21, 20.2125, 17.85, 16.5375, 18.375, 21.2625, 24.9375, 24.15, 34.125, 28.0875],
    [0, 868.125, 759.75, 660, 635.625, 561.75, 520.125, 577.875, 668.625, 784.125, 759.75, 1073.125, 883.125],
    [0, 887.5, 777, 675, 650.625, 575, 533.125, 592.5, 687.5, 806.25, 777, 1100, 907.5],
    [0, 133.875, 117.3, 102, 98.175, 86.7, 80.325, 89.25, 103.275, 121.125, 117.3, 165.75, 136.425],
    [0, 866.25, 759, 660, 635.25, 561, 519.75, 577.5, 668.25, 783.75, 759, 1072.5, 882.75]])
f = np.array([
    [0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8],
    [0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8],
    [0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
])
w = np.array([
    [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
])
b = [
    [7.5, 9.5, 10.0], [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], [0.07, 0.07, 0.07], [1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [7.0, 7.0, 7.0], [7.4, 5.1, 1.5],
    [0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.7, 0.7, 0.7], [1.4, 1.4, 1.4], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
    [1.6, 1.6, 1.6], [1.0, 0.02, 1.0], [0.02, 2.2, 0.02], [6.0, 1.1, 5.6],
    [1.1, 16.0, 10.8], [16.0, 31.0, 16.0], [30.0, 0.6, 31.0], [0.5, 7.0, 1.1],
    [6.7, 17.0, 4.5], [17.0, 0.7, 16.0], [0.7, 0.64, 1.0], [0.72, 1.0, 0.63],
    [11.5, 2.0, 1.6], [2.0, 0.05, 2.0], [0.05, 0.01, 0.05], [0.01, 0.04, 0.01],
    [0.04, 0.18, 0.04], [0.17, 6.8, 0.15], [5.8, 1.0, 4.9], [0.8, 0.07, 0.8],
    [1.0, 1.0, 6.7], [0.07, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    [2.0, 3.0, 3.0], [2.0, 0.2, 3.0], [3.0, 0.3, 1.0], [0.2, 0.3, 4.0],
    [0.3, 0.3, 4.0], [0.3, 1.2, 4.0], [0.3, 0.4, 4.0], [1.2, 0.4, 4.0],
    [0.4, 0.4, 4.0], [0.4, 0.4, 4.0], [0.4, 0.4, 2.0], [0.4, 0.4, 6.0],
    [0.4, 0.4, 3.0], [0.4, 15.0, 5.0], [0.4, 0.6, 1.0], [15.0, 0.25, 1.0],
    [0.6, 5.0, 3.0], [0.25, 1.0, 5.0], [5.0, 1.0, 5.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
    [1.0, 5.0, 1.0], [3.0, 0.05, 5.0], [5.0, 3.0, 5.0], [0.05, 1.0, 5.0],
    [4.0, 1.0, 0.04], [3.0, 5.0, 0.01], [1.2, 0.04, 5.0], [1.0, 0.05, 0.06],
    [1.0, 0.05, 0.04], [5.0, 0.01, 9.68], [0.04, 0.06, 5.0], [0.02, 8.68, 6.0],
    [0.08, 5.0, 5.5], [0.01, 6.0, 3.0], [0.06, 5.5, 1.0], [9.0, 0.01, 5.0],
    [5.0, 3.0, 0.25], [6.0, 1.0, 0.01], [5.5, 5.0, 15.0], [0.01, 0.25, 15.0],
    [3.0, 15.0, 3.2], [1.0, 3.2, 2.5], [5.0, 2.5, 2.0], [0.25, 2.0, 5.0],
    [15.0, 5.0, 0.01], [3.2, 0.01, 0.01], [2.5, 0.01, 0.1], [2.0, 0.75, 0.85],
    [5.0, 1.58, 0.1], [0.01, 0.01, 0.7], [0.01, 0.04, 9.0], [0.75, 1.8, 5.0],
    [1.0, 9.0, 5.0], [2.0, 5.0, 3.0], [0.04, 5.0, 3.0], [1.8, 3.0, 5.0],
    [9.0, 3.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 2.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [3.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    [3.0, 5.0, 3.0], [5.0, 3.0, 5.0], [5.0, 3.0, 3.0], [2.0, 5.0, 3.5],
    [3.0, 3.0, 5.0], [3.0, 3.5, 3.0], [5.0, 5.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0, 2.0],
    [3.5, 2.0, 4.0], [5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0, 0.01], [2.0, 3.0, 0.01],
    [2.0, 0.03, 0.01], [4.0, 1.56, 0.03], [0.03, 2.2, 1.56], [1.56, 0.07, 0.07],
    [0.07, 0.03, 0.03], [0.03, 3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 2.0], [2.0, 0.18, 0.18],
    [0.18, 0.34, 0.34], [0.34, 2.2, 2.2], [2.2, 0.5, 0.6], [0.1, 0.5, 0.5],
    [0.5, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.15, 1.15], [2.0, 3.3, 3.3], [0.02, 0.2, 0.2],
    [1.15, 2.0, 2.0], [3.3, 5.5, 5.5], [0.2, 0.4, 0.4], [2.0, 0.18, 0.18],
    [5.5, 2.7, 2.7], [0.4, 3.0, 2.7], [0.18, 0.32, 0.32], [2.7, 9.6, 10.1],
    [2.7, 2.6, 2.6], [0.32, 0.08, 0.08]
]

wc = np.array([28000, 29000, 30000, 11.66, 12.69, 14.32, 15.17, 15.77, 11.40, 16.29, 18.09, 18.94, 15.17, 18.09, 17.49, 13.11, 12.51, 18.69, 17.49, 17.49, 11.66, 15.17, 17.49, 12.94, 21.00, 21.00, 30.34, 30.34, 15.17, 9.00])
sc = np.array([
    [1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800],
    [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000],
    [2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500],
    [13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90, 13.90],
    [9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34],
    [8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73],
    [16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47, 16.47],
    [15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37, 15.37],
    [30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16, 30.16],
    [6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49, 6.49],
    [24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05, 24.05],
    [5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11, 5.11],
    [26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11, 26.11],
    [15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97, 15.97],
    [9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43, 9.43],
    [31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36, 31.36],
    [30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89, 30.89],
    [19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41, 19.41],
    [8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29, 8.29],
    [6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94],
    [29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54, 29.54],
    [23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16, 23.16],
    [20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24, 20.24],
    [28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83, 28.83],
    [6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27, 6.27],
    [11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91, 11.91],
    [28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68, 28.68],
    [17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48, 17.48],
    [5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10, 5.10],
    [26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71, 26.71],
])
ac = np.array([
    [8.84, 10.60, 18.25, 11.52, 15.89, 17.12, 10.90, 9.84, 15.65, 15.44, 20.50, 10.31],
    [20.73, 11.31, 9.02, 12.67, 8.57, 12.25, 16.03, 18.20, 8.98, 15.72, 15.78, 16.30],
    [14.42, 18.83, 9.75, 17.42, 15.80, 12.93, 16.88, 20.05, 18.82, 10.30, 14.82, 20.78],
    [19.91, 14.55, 19.30, 12.55, 14.51, 13.08, 10.89, 14.46, 12.87, 17.05, 15.30, 16.01],
])
tau = np.array( [0.0560, 0.0640, 0.0667, 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 1, 1.25, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 1, 0.75, 1.25, 1, 0.25, 0.75, 0.5, 1.25, 1.75, 0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 1, 0.75, 1, 0.25, 0.5])
l = np.array([
    150, 250, 300, 53.00, 27560.00, 123.67, 53.00, 5.30, 3.53, 318.00,
    600.67, 3886.67, 2031.67, 5830.00, 353.33, 3533.33, 97.17, 706.67,
    318.00, 47.70, 50500.00, 565.33, 5476.67, 8833.33, 7243.33, 70666.67,
    141.33, 88.33, 194.33, 194.33
])
ma = np.array([
    [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9],
    [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8],
    [0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9],
    [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8],
])
e = np.array([95, 95, 95, 88, 91, 90, 91, 90, 94, 85, 91, 91, 91, 92, 90, 94, 90, 94, 88, 86, 91, 93, 94, 93, 90, 87, 93, 87, 90, 95])
n = np.array([
    0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50,
    0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50,
    0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50
] )
h = np.array([
    0.0160, 0.0200, 0.0150, 0.0164, 0.0082, 0.0246, 0.0246, 0.0164, 0.0329,
    0.0411, 0.0329, 0.0164, 0.0082, 0.0329, 0.0246, 0.0411, 0.0329, 0.0082,
    0.0246, 0.0164, 0.0411, 0.0575, 0.0082, 0.0164, 0.0082, 0.0329, 0.0246,
    0.0329, 0.0082, 0.0164
])
g = [[random.uniform(0.1, 0.5) for r in range(R)] for i in range(I)]
sreal = [[random.randint(10, 50) for t in range(T)] for i in range(I)]
s_initial = np.array([
    300, 750, 800, 200.00, 80333.00, 200.00, 88.00, 5.30, 9.00, 1000.00,
    800.00, 9600.00, 5355.00, 18000.00, 706.00, 9000.00, 210.50, 1879.00,
    1000.00, 150.00, 300000.00, 2789.00, 15000.00, 27000.00, 17890.00,
    200000.00, 356.00, 175.00, 487.00, 562.00
]
) # Or set specific values as per your requirement
# Assuming lambda is given as an input to the function or the script
lambda_param = float(input("Enter the value for lambda: "))

# Initialize the model
m = Model("FuzzyMRP", sense=MINIMIZE)

# Decision variables
p = [[m.add_var() for t in range(T)] for i in range(I)]
q = [[m.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for t in range(T)] for i in range(I)]
s = [[m.add_var() for t in range(T)] for i in range(I)]
a = [[m.add_var() for t in range(T)] for r in range(R)]

sum1 = xsum(p[i][t] * (f[i][r] + (1 - lambda_param) * g[i][r]) + q[i][t] * w[i][r] for i in range(I) for r in range(R) for t in range(T))
# Objective function
m.objective = xsum(a[r][t] * ac[r][t] for r in range(R) for t in range(T)) + \
              xsum(q[i][t] * wc[i] + e[i] * s[i][t] * sc[i][t] for i in range(I) for t in range(T))

# Constraints
# constraint (2):
for r in range(R):
    for t in range(T):
        m += xsum(p[i][t] * f[i][r] + q[i][t] * w[i][r] for i in range(I)) <= 1 + a[r][t]

# constraint (3):
for i in range(I):
    for t in range(T):
        lead_time_adjusted = np.ceil(max(0, t - tau[i]))
        lead_time_adjusted_integer = lead_time_adjusted.astype(int)
        if  lead_time_adjusted  >= 0:
            m += xsum(p[i][t] * b[i][j] for j in range(J)) + d[i][t] + e[i] * s[i][t] == e[i] * s_initial[i] + p[i][lead_time_adjusted_integer]
# constraint (4):
for r in range(R):
    for t in range(T):
        m += a[r][t] <= ma[r][t]

# constraint (5):
for i in range(I):
    for t in range(T):
        m += p[i][t] >= q[i][t] * l[i]

# constraint (7):
for i in range(I):
    for r in range(R):
        for t in range(T):
            m += sum1 <= 1 + a[r][t]

# constraint (10+11):
for i in range(I):
    for t in range(T):
        m += (e[i] + n[i] * (1 - lambda_param)) * s[i][t] <= sreal[i][t]
        m += (e[i] - n[i] * (1 - lambda_param)) * s[i][t] >= sreal[i][t]

# Constraint 8
for i in range(I):
    for t in range(T):
        lead_time_adjusted = max(0, int(t - tau[i] - (1 - lambda_param) * h[i]))
        m += p[i][lead_time_adjusted] + ((e[i] + n[i] * (1 - lambda_param)) * (s[i][t - 1] - s[i][t])) \
             - xsum(p[i][t] * b[i][j] for j in range(J)) <= d[i][t]

# Constraint 9
for i in range(I):
    for t in range(T):
        lead_time_adjusted = np.ceil(max(0, int(t - tau[i] - (1 - lambda_param) * h[i])))
        lead_time_adjusted_integer = lead_time_adjusted.astype(int)
        m += p[i][lead_time_adjusted_integer] + ((e[i] - n[i] * (1 - lambda_param)) * (s[i][t - 1] - s[i][t])) \
             - xsum(p[i][t] * b[i][j] for j in range(J)) >= d[i][t]

# Solve the model
m.optimize()

# Print the objective value
print("Objective Value:", m.objective_value)

# Print the solution
print("Solution:")
for i in range(I):
    for t in range(T):
        print(f"Item {i + 1}, Time {t + 1}: Production = {p[i][t].x}, Inventory = {s[i][t].x}, Binary = {q[i][t].x}")
```